# Are there individual memory allocations for different user roles in WordPress?

Tags: user-roles, post-editor, memory

I am attempting to edit a specific page via the WordPress admin area while logged in as an Editor, however, the page dies with the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in **[PATH]**/htdocs/wp-includes/meta.php on line 841

This is only affecting this page, and granted, it is a very content heavy page, but attempting to edit the page as an Administrator works fine. Why might this be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of this line in `wp-admin/admin.php`:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    wp_raise_memory_limit( 'admin' );
}
```

In other words, WordPress raises the memory limit to `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` within the admin, but only for users with the `manage_options` capability i.e. administrators.

Your best bet is to [raise the default memory limit](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP) in your `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you may try `admin_init` hook and call `wp_raise_memory_limit( 'admin' );`  for the selected user
Example:

```
add_action('admin_init', function(){
   if (  get_current_user_id() === 111111 ){
       wp_raise_memory_limit( 'admin' );   
   }
});
```